Modifyable Styles in Angular Component
I'm working on reusable components in angular.
My Destination is to build a Component whoses styles can be modified by other Users.
As a example there are the following snippets.
There is a nice blue box with a p-Tag, which get styled by the css. Now a other user takes this Component, but needs an other bg-color, color, or wants the div with a rounded border.
Whats the best way to make the Stylings modifyable?
Parameters at the typescript-file seems to be no choice.
A class which contains Parameters like "TextStyle" in Jetpack Compose can not be added in the css-file.
The only solution for me seems to implement the Component and Change the css of the Component directly.
Is this the only way, or can this be done a more elegant way?
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() value: string = '';
}



<div class="container">
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
</div>



.container {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}


You can apply the styles of your component using CSS variables with @property and let the user modify the values for the variables.
Component CSS:
@property --my-component-container-background-color {
  syntax: "<color>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: blue;
}

@property --my-component-container-text-color {
  syntax: "<color>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: white;
}

.container {
  background-color: var(--my-component-container-background-color);
  color: var(--my-component-container-text-color);
}

Now the user can override those variables like the following:
app-my-component {
  --my-component-container-background-color: green;
  --my-component-container-text-color: black;
}

The benefit of this approach is that it supports Angular's emulated view encapsulation.

Thank you for our response :-D
I don't understand how you use this in the components.
Adding a component in html is done the following way:

